# Baking in Cycles ver 2.9 issues

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, uv, light, image

Has anyone else had issues with baking a texture in cycles in the 2.9 version?  Whenever I try to bake the texture, it crashes instantly.  I tried it on a simple plane and cube thinking that my scene was too complex but it does it every time.  The last version of 2.8 still works great.  Is there a new setup, or will it be a bug fix in the future?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such issue with me when i do baking :)
Set render settings to default (Supported , CPU) maybe you are using Experimental for GPU .
I had some Crashes when I was using Experimental for feature set

I hope this helps you
GL.